# How to fix “IR PNP Port not valid”?

Tags: boot, 23.04

When booting up in Ubuntu 23.04 I’m getting below error and it gets stuck:

```
[    9.525103] nuvoton-cir 00:01: IR PNP Port not valid!
[    9.525151] nuvoton-cir: probe of 00:01 failed with error
```

I can only restart my PC - Intel NUC5i7RYH - if I restart in recovery mode and then choose “Resume normal boot”.

This is only happening since I upgraded an old Ubuntu version to 22.x. I managed to upgrade to 23.04 but as I said above still gets stuck when booting up

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.